# Form validation with NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm new to NuxtJS, I was trying to do a simple form to try things out.
The idea is that I have a component that contains the full form

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>
      {{ title }}
    </h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <input type="email" v-model="email" />
      <input type="password" v-model="password" />
      <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      title: 'Sign in',
      email: null,
      password: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit: function() {
      console.log('Hello')
    } 
  } 
}
</script>
```

It's nothing crazy, and then I'm just calling this component in my page

```html
<template>
  <LoginForm />
</template>

<script>

export default {
}
</script>
```

But when I submit my form I can't see my message in the console, I'm wondering what I did wrong or did I miss something ?
Also it is a good practice to make a component like this or should I divide more my component into small one's ?

Comment: It's working totally fine on my side. Not sure what's the issue here. Do you have any error on the page (console) or in your editor (with ESlint)?

Comment: In terms of practice, there is no universal question to this. For me, it looks perfectly fine. (SO doesn't like opinion-based question too, so will not get a lot of feedback on this one)

Comment: Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: Hey @kissu, I have no errors and it's really weird that I have no message in my console. Thank you anyone i'll figure out what's wrong and i'll post it here :)
( My minimal reproducible exemple is this one xD )

Comment: If you give us a [repro], we can probably figure out this one.